# Flutter Appwrite Error: "document_not_found" (404) - Need Quick Assistance

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, appwrite

I'm encountering an issue in my Flutter app where I'm using the Appwrite library for backend services. I'm getting the following error:

```
    Exception has occurred.
AppwriteException (AppwriteException: document_not_found, Document with the requested ID could not be found. (404))
```

This error occurs in the **client_io.dart** file. I'm trying to build a screen where users can create posts, and I'm fetching the current user's data from an **Appwrite** provider using Riverpod.

Here's a version of my code:

```
    class CreatePostScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  static route() => MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => const CreatePostScreen(),
      );
  const CreatePostScreen({super.key});

  @override
  ConsumerState<ConsumerStatefulWidget> createState() =>
      _CreatePostScreenState();
}

class _CreatePostScreenState extends ConsumerState<CreatePostScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final currentUser = ref.watch(currentUserDetailsProvider).value;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.close,
            size: 30,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
        ),
        actions: [
          RoundedSmallButton(
            onTap: () {},
            label: 'Post',
            backgroundColor: Pallete.pinkColor,
            TextColor: Pallete.whiteColor,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: currentUser == null
          ? const Loader()
          : SafeArea(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundImage: NetworkImage(currentUser.profilePic),
                          radius: 30,
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm not sure what's causing this error, and I could really use some help to understand and fix it. If you have any insights or suggestions, please let me know. I need to resolve this issue quickly, as it's a critical part of my app.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to update permissions . Allow read from your collection.Check screenshot for reference